# How to circumvent slow search with Index() method for a large list

Tags: python

I have a large list `myList` containing tuples.

I need to remove the duplicates in this list (that is the tuples with same elements in the same order). I also need to keep track of this list's indices in a separate list, `indexList`. If I remove a duplicate, I need to change its index in `indexList` to first identical value's index.

To demonstrate what I mean, if `myList` looks like this:

```
myList = [(6, 2), (4, 3), (6, 2), (8, 1), (5, 4), (4, 3), (2, 1)]
```

Then I need to construct `indexList` like this:

```
indexList = (0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 4)
```

Here the third value is identical to first, so it (third value) gets index `0`. Also the subsequent value gets an updated index of `2` and so on.

Here is how I achieved this:

```
unique = set()
i = 0
for v in myList[:]:
    if v not in unique:
        unique.add(v)
        indexList.append(i)
        i = i+1
    else:
        myList.pop(i)
        indexList.append(myList.index(v))
```

This does what I need. However `index()` method makes the script very slow when `myList` contains hundreds of thousands of elements. As I understand this is because it's an `O(n) operation`.

So what changes could I make to achieve the same result but make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a dict to store the first index of each value, you can do the lookup in `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`. So in this case, before the for loop, do `indexes = {}`, and then in the `if` block, do `indexes[v] = i` and in the `else` block use `indexes[v]` instead of `myList.index(v)`.